# Returning back to last state in previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B. When the application starts, activity A is loaded and I load data to it from database.
I can go to activity B without any problems, but when I go back to activity A, the old data are viewed for a moment and the activity is reloaded.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please show your code on how you call and return activity

Comment: Show your code. No need to StartActivity A From B. You just need to Finish(); Activity B. You Have Automatically Redirect to last stage of Activity A. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Clear all fields before loading data start from DB.loading data from take little time and before this clear previous field.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in my device, the app worked perfectly on another device!

Answer (score 0):

Here You can put all field as blank..

You need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the application activity state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  /* Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  * This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  * killed and restarted activity
  */
  savedInstanceState.putString("YourString", "");

  // etc...
  // etc...
}
```

The Bundle is essentially a way of storing a NVP ("Name-Value Pair") map, and it will get passed in to onCreate() and also onRestoreInstanceState() where you'd extract the values like this:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.

  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("YourString");
}
```

You would usually use this technique to store instance values for your application (selections, unsaved text) etc.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in my device, the app worked perfectly on another device!

Comment: Did you check that why its happened ?  just debug it you will find it.